# Why doesn't the value of SPAN update

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

ASP.net:

```
<span id="lblScore" class="lblScore">Your Score is: 0</span>
<asp:Label ID="lblHiddenScore" runat="server" CssClass="lblHScore" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

The following jquery is executed after a certain event:

```
$(".lblScore").text("");
$(".lblScore").text("Your Score is: " + score);
$(".lblHScore").text(score);
```

I can see in the front-end, the value is changing but when I view the source of the HTML, it doesn't show the changes.

I am trying to use the `score` value from code-behind:

```
string yr = lblHiddenScore.Text; //it is always ""
```

How can I retrieve the value from the front end to use in code-behind

Comment: `view source` is what your browser fetched from the server. it does **NOT** show any changes made by JS after the page was loaded. you have to use your browser's dom inspector to see the "live" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels are not posted back to the server, as they are not part of the form data, hence you cannot read the text of it at the server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what is the best way to access it?

Comment: I tried using hiddenfield but that didn't work either for me.